# Google Cloud Platform VM: https

Tags: ssl, docker, https, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

Docker compose running 2 containers inside GCP VM:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "443:8080"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/www
      - /www/node_modules
```

Port redirect set to 443, firewall configured (i guess), but still i can't connect to server through https. It's available only on http://ip_address:443

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you are assuming that just because you are using port 443 the traffic becomes SSL.

If something on port `443` is accessible as `http://<IP>:443/` that means you are running a plain HTTP application on 443.

So you in your NodeJS server would be creating a simple server without the Certificate and private key.

There are two options you have

**Use SSL Server in Code**

You can update your NodeJS code to listen as a https server. Something like below

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

**Put nginx in front for serving**

You can add a nginx with SSL configuration and then proxy pass the traffic to your NodeJS app

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/www
      - /www/node_modules
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./www:/usr/local/var/www
```

You will need to create a nginx conf file

```
server {
  listen       80;
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  _;

  ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api-server:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  location /public {
    root /usr/local/var/www;
  }

}
```

PS: For more details refer to https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/